# row values on pie slices python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plotter

    pieLabels              = 'Asia', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'North America', 'South America', 'Australia'
    populationShare     = [5.69, 16, 9.94, 7.79, 5.68, 6.54]
```

To make the pie:

```
figureObject, axesObject = plotter.subplots()
axesObject.pie(populationShare,
        labels=pieLabels,
        startangle=90)
axesObject.axis('equal')
plotter.show()
```

I want to make a pie chart and have the actual value of populationShare printed on the slices of the pie. NOT a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plotter

pieLabels  = ['Asia', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'North America', 'South America', 'Australia']
populationShare = [5.69, 16, 9.94, 7.79, 5.68, 6.54]

figureObject, axesObject = plotter.subplots()
axesObject.pie(populationShare,
               labels=pieLabels,
               autopct=lambda p: '{:.2f}'.format(p * sum(populationShare) / 100),
               startangle=90)
axesObject.axis('equal')
plotter.show()
```

Comment: what does {:.0f) do ? there is an invalid syntax and cant figure out where

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the full code. In terms of your data you need to use {:.2f}. It means you are displaying the values with two decimal places. Try the code, if it works please accept my answer. Thank you. @RedaS